# How to create a variable that indicates agreement from two dichotomous variables

Tags: r, binary

I d like to create a new variable that contains 1 and 0. A 1 represents agreement between the rater (both raters 1 or both raters 0) and a zero represents disagreement.

```
rater_A <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
rater_B <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
df <- cbind(rater_A, rater_B)
```

The new variable would be like the following vector I created manually:

```
df$agreement <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
```

Maybe there's a package or a function I don't know. Any help would be great.

Comment: Wondering why you don't work with logical (TRUE/FALSE) vectors in the first place. And use logical operators (`?Logic`), here `!xor(rater_A, rater_B)` or `rater_A == rater_B`

Comment: Thanks, working with logical operators did the job. My finals solution to my problem is as follows:`df$agreement = as.numeric(rater_A == rater_B)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `df` as a `data.frame` (instead of using `cbind`) and use `within` and `ifelse`:

```
rater_A <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
rater_B <- c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(rater_A, rater_B)
##
df <- within(df,
  agreement <- ifelse(
    rater_A==rater_B,1,0))
##
> df
   rater_A rater_B agreement
1        1       1         1
2        0       1         0
3        1       0         0
4        1       0         0
5        1       1         1
6        0       1         0
7        0       0         1
8        1       1         1
9        0       0         1
10       0       0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with 3 functions: c(), ifelse() and cbind()

```
rater_A <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
rater_B <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
agreement <- ifelse(rater_A == rater_B, 1, 0)
cbind(rater_A, rater_B, agreement)
```